# Highstock Chart - setExtremes event data missing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a chart with the following specs:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            alignTicks: false,
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 5,
            buttons: [
                {
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
                }, {
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 10,
                    text: '10m'
                }, {
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 30,
                    text: '30m'
                }, {
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 60,
                    text: '1h'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1d'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }
            ]
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Ping RTT over time for: ' + host
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            events: {
                setExtremes: setExtremesCallback
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Ping RTT (ms)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[c]
            },
            series: {
                dataGrouping: {
                    approximation: "average"
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Ping RTT',
            data: h,
        }]
    });
```

Then I have the `setExtreme` callback defined as follows:

```
function setExtremeCallback(event) {
    var min = event.min;
    var max = event.max;
    var container = event.target.chart.renderTo
    ...
}
```

In this function i would like to compute some statistics regarding the portion of data in the selected range. For this I need `min` and `max`, and I'm able to catch them from the `event` object.
The problem is that don't manage to access the `data` array. I've tried with

```
var data = event.target.chart.series[0].data
```

or

```
var data = this.series[0].data
```

but both of them are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way, but I'm pretty sure there is a cleaner way to do that.

```
function setExtremeCallback(event) {
    var minPos = 0;
    var maxPos = this.series[0].xData.length - 1;
    for (var j = 0; j < this.series[0].xData.length; j++) {
        if (this.series[0].xData[j] <= event.min)
            minPos = j;
        if (this.series[0].xData[j] <= event.max)
            maxPos = j;
    }
    var yData = this.series[0].yData.slice(minPos, maxPos);
    ...
}
```